# Access SVN server over HTTP in Windows

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have installed VisualSVN Server in a windows machine. And TortoiseSVN client in another server. I want to access the data of VisualSVN server through TortoiseSVN over http or https. How can I do that?

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Just tell `TortoiseSVN` the URL of your repo:

1. Open `VisualSVN Server Manager`. Under repositories, select your repository, right click > `Copy URL to clipboard.`
2. Go to other machine, rigth click on folder where you want to checkout the code > `SVN Checkout...`, paste the above value in the field `URL of the repository` (TortoiseSVN might even pre-populate this for you from clipboard). Click OK.

That's all.